# Convert Selenium Java tests into Protractor tests

Tags: selenium, protractor

I have a bunch of Selenium tests written in Java.

Is there a way to covert them to Protractor tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30010/moving-from-selenium-to-protractor.  As far as I know there is no trivial way to make this transition.

Taking tests that are written directly in Selenium and transitioning to Protractor is almost like writing them from scratch especially if my assumption is correct that the devs are totally rewriting the front end with angular.

HOWEVER, you do have a test framework and a list of tests which is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to write framework and all tests from scratch if you use Protractor and you have to learn lot of new things, below are some points for observation.

1. Protractor supports `javascript` language to write `unit/regression/functional` tests, but js syntax is different from java, you can understand its flavor but syntax is completely different. e.g. `import` becomes `require`
2. Different synchronization, no automatic waits etc, require usage of promises resolution using `.then`. js script control flow is `not synchronous` unlike java so understanding it is very important and bit tedious.
3. Different reporting libraries like `jasmine allure reports`,`jetty reports` etc
4. Different unit testing frameworks like `jasmine`  instead of junit/testng.
5. The existing framework will not be helpful because protractor nodejs framework have different project structure then java's maven project.
6. Existing utilities like xls reading and writing, loggers etc will be purely different libraries and not easy like `.jxl/apache-poi`

Suggestions =>

1. If you have time you should use Protractor.
2. Else you can use `ngWebDriver`=> This is an extension to WebDriver for handling angular based applications and supports writing angular tests using JAVA. This is written by Paul Hamant. You can kick start using [link](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver/tree/master/src/test/java/com/paulhammant/ngwebdriver).But consider synchronization is not as good as Protractor,documentation and issue support is limited.

Comment: @DebanjanB - yes in newer version we have `async` and `await` for better synchronizations...

Comment: OP should use protractor, synchronization is hard enough with that.  No offense to Paul Hamant, but..... he should use protractor.